# Разбить данные на массивы строк

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Как разбить спарсенные данные в массивы строк?

```
<?php
    header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    require ('phpQuery.php');

    $ch = curl_init('http://allhyips.ru/sitemap.xml');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $url = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($url);
    $hyipurl = $doc->find('loc')->html();

    $new = explode("http", $hyipurl);

    echo $new;


    ?>
```

Comment: Вы нам предлагаете найти phpQuery.php, запустить ваш скрипт и посмотреть какие данные нужно разбить? Еще протелепатировать условия разбиения на строки?

Comment: Примерно скажите как это сделать. В результате скрипт выводит ссылки на материалы одной строкой (http://allhyips.ru/betbuddy_ltdhttp://allhyips.ru/binar-option_orghttp://allhyips.ru/globex_tophttp://allhyips.ru/liteincome_ltdhttp://allhyips.ru/merilinvest_tradehttp://allhyips.ru/wristfix_net). Мне нужно, чтоб каждая ссылка получила свой номер строки.

Comment: если у вас там xml, то и работайте с соответствующими инструментами

Comment: Пока надеялся на вашу помощь, сам научился это выполнять. Благодарю за попытку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам уже сказали лучше использовать штатные средства, чем библиотеки

```
$ch = curl_init('http://allhyips.ru/sitemap.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($html) or die("url not loading");

//echo $xml->url[0]->loc;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml); $i++) {
    echo $i . '. ' . $xml->url[$i]->loc . '<br>';
}

//выведет
//0. http://allhyips.ru/betbuddy_ltd
//1. http://allhyips.ru/binar-option_org
//2. http://allhyips.ru/globex_top
//3. http://allhyips.ru/liteincome_ltd
//4. http://allhyips.ru/merilinvest_trade
//5. http://allhyips.ru/wristfix_net
//6. http://allhyips.ru/bank-england_com
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!